# RadioButton.Checked inside Tree

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, radio-button

At first i had a list which contained generated radiobuttons. This looked like this:

```
foreach (Team TeamName in loadOperation.Entities)
{
    RadioButton radiobutton = new RadioButton();
    radiobutton.GroupName = "ticketfilter";
    radiobutton.Content = TeamName.Name.ToString();

    int teamid = TeamName.TeamID;
    radiobutton.Checked += new RoutedEventHandler((s, e) => FilterForTeam(s, e, teamid));
    radiobutton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler((s, e) => LoadTickets());

    UserRadioButtons.Children.Add(radiobutton);
}
```

As a result, this gave me a list of RadioButtons. However, i want to turn this list in to a Tree view.
So i did the following:

```
foreach (Team TeamName in loadOperation.Entities)
{
    TreeViewItem tree = new TreeViewItem();
    tree.Header = new RadioButton()
    {
        GroupName = "ticketfilter",
        Content = TeamName.Name.ToString(),
    };


    int count = TeamName.TeamMemberships.Select(d => d.User.UserID).Count();
    int startcount = 0;
    while (startcount < count)
    {
        tree.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem()
        {
            Header = new RadioButton()
            {
                GroupName = "ticketfilter",
                Content = TeamName.TeamMemberships.Select(d => d.User.FullName).Skip(startcount).FirstOrDefault(),
                //checked = something // This turns into .Ischecked,
            }
        });
        startcount++;
    }

    UserRadioButtons.Children.Add(tree);
}
```

Now this is giving me the result i want.
However, i can't add the Property **Checked** to my RadioButton.

Is there a way that i can assign Propertys like **.Checked** and **.Click** to the RadioButtons inside my tree view?

***EDIT:***

Example of what i'm doing now.

```
public class MyRadioButtonItem
{
    public RadioButton MyRadioButton { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    public string Groupname { get; set; }
}
```

And then later i define it like this:

```
TreeViewItem tree = new TreeViewItem();
tree.Header = new MyRadioButtonItem()
{
    Groupname = "ticketfilter",
    content = TeamName.Name.ToString(),
 };
```

It recognizes all the things i'm defining. 
However, i need option like: Clicked and checked.

But for example in this example. How does the radiobutton know the difference between GroupName and Content. 
For example Groupname could be content since they are both strings?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a custom class like this:

```
public class MyRadioButtonItem
{
  public RadioButton MyRadioButton {get; set;}
  public bool IsChecked {get; set;}
}
```

and then use it in place of `RadioButton`

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: When i do this, the radiobutton assigned controls get recognized. However. This does not work. Becuase if i assign Content in my public class. And use it in the private void. How does the radiobutton know which is the content? Becuase a string title or test could also be one.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this and if possible, show some example code?